# Hover stays active, until mouseover another hoverable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hover, jquery-animate

Lets say I have three boxes. Each of which can be hovered on, and when so, their background color changes to red.

I want to make it so even when your mouse leaves the box (and doesn't touch another box that can be hoverable), it stays active.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LvtWB/2/

I want to be able to hover on one of these, turn it red, and when the mouse goes into the white space, the background change stays active. Once the mouse goes into another box, only then can it go back to normal.

How can I achieve this?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').eq(1).animate({
        backgroundColor: "red"
    }, 800);
    $('.box').hover(function(){
        $('.box').stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "green"
        }, 800);
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "red"
        }, 800);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "green"
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the second function call of hover:

```
$('.box').eq(1).animate({
    backgroundColor: "red"
}, 800);
$('.box').hover(function () {
    $('.box').stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "green"
    }, 800);
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "red"
    }, 800);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LvtWB/12/)**

Or without using hover (since you're not using the second part anyway):

```
$('.box').eq(1).animate({
    backgroundColor: "red"
}, 800);
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.box').stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "green"
    }, 800);
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "red"
    }, 800);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LvtWB/15/)**

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `mouseenter` event instead of the `hover` event.

http://jsfiddle.net/LvtWB/18/